# Json rule to add newline in a array

Tags: java, json, libgdx

Hello how can I make that when i parse a array of ints to json that every 5. value will be a newline. I use libGDX.

```
data: {
4, 7, 3, 6, 9,
4, 9, 0, 2, 6,
...
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far, Are you using soem api for JSON handling or what can you ost more detsils

Comment: I have no idea how to handle this. I use libGDXs JSON class.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested it, but from looking at the LibGDX Json API this might do what you want:

```
prettyPrint(java.lang.String json, int singleLineColumns)
```

"singleLineColumns: If an object on a single line fits this many columns, it won't wrap."

So try putting 5 in for singleLineColumns and see if that works.

Comment: I will try this at home. Only problem will be that ich have 2 different arrays that have different needs with wraping.

Comment: Can you call the prettyPrint method on each array separately with different singleLineColumns values? If the two arrays are contained inside of another object, you could pass the Json object into that object and then write the two arrays separately. Would something like this work?